# How many numbers less than $500$ can you make using the digits $0,2,4,6,8$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm having trouble breaking down the solution for this problem.  I think its poorly worded but was hoping someone may have some insight.

> How many numbers less than $500$ can you make using the digits $0,2,4,6,8$?

Can't I have an infinite number of zeros?

Comment: Unless you want to argue that, say, $\{2,02,002,\cdots\}$ are all different, then, you can't use infinitely many $0's$ helpfully.  It isn't clear to me if you are allowed to use each digit more than once, but even if you are there are still only finitely many.

Comment: How many times can each of $ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8$ be used in any one number?  E.g., does 242 count? (Uses "2" twice).    Of course, any number less than 500 will not have an infinite number of zeros. So does $000 = 0$count?

Comment: I'm assuming the digits can repeat in this question as the question after this one asks to assume the digits don't repeat.  I'm just struggling with how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: "Can't I have an infinite number of zeros?"  There is only one way to have an infinite number of zeros so that doesn't counter anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $100x+10y+z<500$ can have an $x$ value of either $0,\,2$ or $4$ whereas $y$ and $z$ can be any of the five numbers (assuming negative numbers are excluded).

So there are $3\times5\times5=75$ possible numbers. (or $74$ in the case of positive numbers).

Comment: I get it now!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer to John Wayland Bales' is to assume they meant you can't use any digit twice.  (it isn't clear if they meant this or not.  If they didn't John Wayland Bales' has the correct answer.  If they didn't mine will be.)

Infinite leading zeros do not count as using zero.  e.g.  $.....0000000007 = 7$ does not count as using zero.  So $.........000000507 = 507$ counts as using ero exactly once.

There are three options:

1) The number $n$ is $0 \le n \le 9$.  There are 5 such numbers ($0, 2,4,5,8$)

2) The number $n$ is $10 \le n\le 99$.  There are 4 choices for the first digit ($2,4,6,8$) and 4 choices for the second (anything that is not the first digit).  So there are $4*4 = 16$ such numbers.

3) the nummber $n$ is $100 \le n \le 500$.  There are 4 choices for the first diagit ($2,4,6,8$) and four choices for the second (anything that is not the first digit) and three choices for the third (anything that is neither of the first two).  So there are $4*4*3 =48$ such numbers.

So there are $5+16+48 = 69$ such numbers.